# Gfortran returns an error when writing output

Tags: macos, gfortran

I recently updated from `gfortran v5.1 to v8.2.0.` I try to run the simple program named `test1.f90` in an iMac with Intel Core i5

---

```
program test1

  write(6,*) '1'

  open(8,file='gamma.out')

  write(6,*) '2'

end program test1
```

---

I compile it using

```
gfortran test1.f90 -o test1.x
```

and when running it I get the output

---

```
 1

At line 3 of file test1.f90 (unit = 8, file = '')

Fortran runtime error: Bad address
```

---

Then I tried the program test2.f90:

---

program test2

```
write(6,*) '1'

  x=1.0

  write(6,*) '2'

  write(6,*) x

  write(6,*) '3'

  write(6,'(f10.5)') x

  write(6,*) '4'

end program test2
```

---

The output I get now is:

---

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 1.00000000
>
> 3

Program received signal `SIGSEGV`: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

> #0  0x104c622d2
>
> #1  0x104c62a8e
>
> #2  0x7fff6f4c1b5c
>
> #3  0x104d222a0
>
> #4  0x104d31197
>
> #5  0x104c5bdf4
>
> #6  0x104c5bebc
>
> Segmentation fault

---

The operating system is MOJAVE 10.14.6.

gfortran --version yields 8.2.0

I installed this new version of gfortran using the .dmg installer available at https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/8.2

Any ideas of what can be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please tell us other details. What kind of operating system do you use? How did you install the new version? Is the old version still there? Run `gfortran -v` end [edit] the result into the question.

Comment: The operating System is MOJAVE 10.14.6. gfortan --version yields 8.2.0. I installed it using the .dmg available at https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases/tag/8.2.

Comment: Try homebrew, most people here use it.